# Returning variable from directive instead of exposing the scope

Tags: angularjs

In the code below I have a directive that calculates a variable `y` every time an input field `x` is changed. The variable `y` is exposed, so it's available to the declaring controller/directive. This works fine but it's a simple abstraction, in my real scenario the computation of `y` is very expensive, so I cannot afford to calculate `y` every time `x` changes. Ideally, I would calculate `y` only when the declaring controller/directive needs it. Is there a way to achieve that?

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctl', function () {

});

app.directive("theDirective", function() {
      return {
        restrict: "AE", 
        scope: {
           y: '='
        },
        template: '<input ng-model="x" ng-change="xChanged()" />',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.xChanged = function() { 
                 scope.y = scope.x * 2;
            };

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need this data from a child of this directive you can accomplish this by exposing a method in your directives controller and then exposing a method that the child directive can require.

```
app.directive("theDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "AE", 
    scope: {
       y: '='
    },
    template: '<input ng-model="x" ng-change="xChanged()" />',
    controller: function (scope) {

        scope.getY = function() { 
             return scope.x * 2;
        };

    }
}
});
```

And then your chid can require the parent can call that method.

```
app.directive("theDirectiveChild", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A", 
    require: ["^theDirective"],
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls){

      var theDirective = ctrls[0];

      var y = theDirective.getY();

    }
}
});
```

EDIT: To do the opposite, where you want the parent to tell the child to update, you can utilize $scope.broadcast() This can fire a message down the scope chain, it would look something like this.

```
app.directive("theDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "AE", 
    scope: {
       y: '='
    },
    template: '<input ng-model="x" ng-change="xChanged()" />',
    link: function (scope) {

        scope.on('update-the-directive' , function() {
           scope.y = scope.x * 2;
        });

    }
}
});
```

And then your chid can require the parent can call that method.

```
app.directive("theDirectiveParent", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A", 
    link: function(scope, element){

      scope.click = function() {
        scope.$broadcast('update-the-directive');
      }

    }
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the function in the directive to be called from the parent and not from a child

Comment: Edited my answer to include that scenario as well.

Comment: There's a problem with this approach. Since `$broadcast` is async, if the function in the child takes time to process the parent will not know when it ends, therefore it cannot take the variable from the scope.

Comment: That sounds like more a design problem, $broadcast and $on are synchronous, if the function in the child takes time you should wait for that to complete before sending the data using $broadcast.